# background image behind css element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put a background image behind my opening door css element and cannot for the life of me figure it out!

code located here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydAKz

had to include underneath code to post

```
 script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <p class="alert"></p>
    <div class="perspective" onclick="openDoor(this)">
        <div class="thumb">
        </div>
    </div>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gqkxv)

```
body
{
  /*background-color:#f0f0f0;*/
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR2BmZU1kR795PbCjY--wGWcdHvgdq4oM43UgpHSGKF6rk-qrhMiEFqGFe-) no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: fantastic Alex, thank you very much! i tried body background url and didn't work previously